# Streaming replication is failing with "WAL segment has already been moved"

Tags: postgresql, replication

I am trying to implement Master/Slave streaming replication on `Postgres 11.5`.  I ran the following steps -

On Master

```
select pg_start_backup('replication-setup',true);
```

On Slave
Stopped the postgres 11 database and ran

```
rsync -aHAXxv --numeric-ids --progress -e "ssh -T -o Compression=no -x" --exclude pg_wal --exclude postgresql.pid --exclude pg_log MASTER:/var/lib/postgresql/11/main/* /var/lib/postgresql/11/main
```

On Master

```
select pg_stop_backup();
```

On Slave

```
rsync -aHAXxv --numeric-ids --progress -e "ssh -T -o Compression=no -x"  MASTER:/var/lib/postgresql/11/main/pg_wal/* /var/lib/postgresql/11/main/pg_wal
```

I created the `recovery.conf` file  on slave ~/11/main folder

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user=postgres host=MASTER port=5432 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres'
primary_slot_name='my_repl_slot'
```

When I start Postgres on Slave, I get the error on both MASTER and SLAVE logs -

```
019-11-08 09:03:51.205 CST [27633] LOG:  00000: database system was interrupted; last known up at 2019-11-08 02:53:04 CST
2019-11-08 09:03:51.205 CST [27633] LOCATION:  StartupXLOG, xlog.c:6388
2019-11-08 09:03:51.252 CST [27633] LOG:  00000: entering standby mode
2019-11-08 09:03:51.252 CST [27633] LOCATION:  StartupXLOG, xlog.c:6443
2019-11-08 09:03:51.384 CST [27634] LOG:  00000: started streaming WAL from primary at 12DB/C000000 on timeline 1
2019-11-08 09:03:51.384 CST [27634] LOCATION:  WalReceiverMain, walreceiver.c:383
2019-11-08 09:03:51.384 CST [27634] FATAL:  XX000: could not receive data from WAL stream: ERROR:  requested WAL segment 00000001000012DB0000000C has already been removed
2019-11-08 09:03:51.384 CST [27634] LOCATION:  libpqrcv_receive, libpqwalreceiver.c:772
2019-11-08 09:03:51.408 CST [27635] LOG:  00000: started streaming WAL from primary at 12DB/C000000 on timeline 1
2019-11-08 09:03:51.408 CST [27635] LOCATION:  WalReceiverMain, walreceiver.c:383
```

The problem is the START WAL - `00000001000012DB0000000C` is available right until I run the `pg_stop_backup()` and is getting archived and no longer available, once the `pg_stop_backup()` is executed.  So this is not an issue of the WAL being archived out due to low `WAL_KEEP_SEGMENTS`.

```
postgres@SLAVE:~/11/main/pg_wal$ cat 00000001000012DB0000000C.00000718.backup
START WAL LOCATION: 12DB/C000718 (file 00000001000012DB0000000C)
STOP WAL LOCATION: 12DB/F4C30720 (file 00000001000012DB000000F4)
CHECKPOINT LOCATION: 12DB/C000750
BACKUP METHOD: pg_start_backup
BACKUP FROM: master
START TIME: 2019-11-07 15:47:26 CST
LABEL: replication-setup-mdurbha
START TIMELINE: 1
STOP TIME: 2019-11-08 08:48:35 CST
STOP TIMELINE: 1
```

My MASTER has `archive_command` set, and I have the missing WALs available. I copied them into a restore directory on the SLAVE and tried the `recovery.conf` below, but it still fails with the MASTER reporting the same `WAL segment has already been moved` error.
Any idea how I can address this issue?  I have used rsync to setup replication without any issues in the past on Postgres 9.6, but have been experiencing this issue on Postgres 11.

```
standby_mode = 'on'
primary_conninfo = 'user=postgres host=MASTER port=5432 sslmode=prefer sslcompression=1 krbsrvname=postgres'
restore_command='cp /var/lib/postgresql/restore/%f %p'
```

Comment: Are you sure the restore failed?  It might ask for the file, be told it isn't there and report an ERROR, then proceed with the file it already has.

Comment: It is failing, as it keeps repeating the same error on the same WAL, and does not get to a consistent state. psql connection fails as well.

Comment: you pasted two contents of `recovery.conf` in your question -- are they related?  One has `restore_command` and the other doesn't

Comment: I would edit restore_command to put something like "echo trying to copy %f %p;" in front of the real cp command, to make sure the output of this command is actually getting captured in your logs and/or that it is being run.  Also, it might make your logs cleaner and easier to understand if you temporarily comment out the primary_conninfo.

Comment: Did you restart the replica after changing the recovery.conf to add the restore_command to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `restore_command` into `recovery.conf` that can restore archived WAL files and you are fine.

Comment: So you are saying - include both `restore_command` and `primary_slot_name` within the recovery.conf?.  Any idea why the leading WAL is getting archived and removed by `pg_stop_backup()`?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. You have `primary_conninfo` too, right? The current WAL segment is archived by `pg_stop_backup` because without it the backup is not complete. It is required for recovery.

Comment: Thanks very much.  I will try it next time I have this issue. I have posted a solution on how I fixed it.

Comment: I resolved it by running the pg_stop_backup() on the master, after starting postgres on the slave and initiating recovery.  That way, the leading WAL is not archived before the recovery starts.  Not sure if that's a good approach...but it fixed my issue.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be correct. An incorrect setup may corrupt the standby. You should either follow my advice or increase `wal_keep_segments` on the primary.